# Allowing user to have 2nd attempt at getting right answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my drag and drop spelling game I have designed it so when the correct letters are dragged onto the corresponding words, a style is applied (wordglow2) that makes it disappear and reveal the picture behind - which is the aim of the game. The problem is that when the user gets the word wrong the he/she isn't given a second attempt at the word, so it stays in the grid meaning the game cannot be completed. After the style is applied for wrong words (wordglow) I need it to be attempt able again, can someone help?

```
$(".drop").droppable({
drop: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));
    console.log($(event));
    console.log($(ui.draggable).text());

    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    if ($(this).text() == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {

        $(this).addClass('wordglow3');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('wordglow');
    }
    console.log('CHECKING : ' + $(this).text() + ' against ' + $(ui.draggable).text().trim());


    console.log(guesses);

    if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
        if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow2");

        } else {
            $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");

        }
    }


},

activate: function(event, ui) {
    word = $(this).data('word');

    // try to remove the class
    $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').removeClass('wordglow').removeClass('wordglow4').removeClass('wordglow3');
}


});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628578/allowing-user-to-have-2nd-attempt-at-getting-right-answer?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you just fill an array in order to check whether the word is correct. But this isn't enough. Say I want to solve "top", but I'm lazy and start with "p" since my mouse pointer is near this particular letter. Then the array will consists of the single letter `['p']` and the word is not longer solvable.

Instead check *which* letter you're currently manipulating, save the letters at the correct position and use an array with a fixed with of 3 instead of `Array.push`.

However, if you don't want the user to be able to provide a wrong order you can simply delete the old guess (see [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)):

```
if (guesses[word].length == 3) {
    if (guesses[word].join('') == word) {
        $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow2");

    } else {
        $('td[data-word=' + word + ']').addClass("wordglow4");
        guesses[word].splice(0,guesses[word].length);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it so you have to spell it in the correct order. My problem is once a word is spelt wrong it cannot be made right and disappear to reveal the image @Zeta

Comment: Well, how should one be able to correct it? If they shall only provide the correct order, then the only possibility to correct the error is to delete the guess.

Comment: They have to start the word from the start rather than fill in the incorrect spots. This way it will give the children it is designed for better practice at constructing simple words. @Zeta

Comment: I edited my answer - easiest approach is to delete the old guess and start over. However, I believe you'll have to remove `worddglow4` sooner or later in your script.

Comment: Thanks @Zeta , just what I was looking for. There is a reason for wordglow4, it makes the wrong word glow red without any green.